# How to add noise to time series data in Python?

Tags: noise, python

I have time series data with $x$, $y$, $z$ sampled at $50\textrm{ Hz}$ from a sensor and I would like to add a uniform and Laplace noise to it. How would I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Could you please recommend the right site for such a question? I posted a similar question on stackoverflow.com and I haven't gotten any response yet here I got someone who gave me a hint which I am trying out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments:

1. I'm not sure if this is the right forum for python questions.
2. You left some relevant information, like the type of variable your data is stored.
3. I assume that "la place" is laplace distribution.

Please see if this helps, and make the necessary adjustments:

```
import numpy as np
def fn_addnoise(data):
    i = len(data)
    # create 1D numpy data:
    npdata = np.asarray(data).reshape((i))
    # add uniform noise:
    u = npdata + np.random.uniform(size=npdata.shape)
    # add laplace noise:
    p = npdata + np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=npdata.shape)

    print npdata
    print u
    print p
    return u,p
# 'data' might be a tuple...
data = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
# or a list...
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
fn_addnoise(data)
```